# Eclipse gradle mc modding bug

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

So this is the error i get everytime i try to run: "gradlew eclipse" or "gradlew genEclipseRuns" inside the cmd.

```
Could not resolve: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.13.2-25.0.84_mapped_snapshot_20180921-1.13
```

i'm following an modding tutorial on youtube, but i can't continue with these errors.

i've already tried

1. Restarting my pc.
2. Restarting Eclipse and switching to the enterprise version of eclipse, with no luck.
3. Tried other software with other forge version.
4. Cleaned folders and projects multiple times.

I've already spent 6 hours with these problems, with no way to know how to solve this.
Anyone might know this issue and know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried `gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse`?

Comment: the amount of errors dissapeared with that command, but it says it is still missing the net.minecraftforge:forge:1.13.2-25.0.84_mapped_snapshot_20180921-1.13.